# How to override an app route from a package in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, oop, composer-php, laravel-6

I am attempting to create a composer package for Laravel 6 but I can not get my main route `/` to override the default `/` route included with the base Laravel installation.

My package route does works when I comment out the base `/` route provided by laravel so it is being registered by the package.

It doesn't make any different if I include my package's service provider before or after the RouteServiceProvider in the `config/app.php` file.

What am I missing here?  How do I ensure my package routes have priority?

Here are the relevant bits of code:

`config/app.php`

```
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
Wheelmaker\LaravueSpa\LaravueSpaServiceProvider::class,  // MY SERVICE PROVIDER
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

The relevant section of `LaravueSpaServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
  $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/web.php');
  ...
}
```

My Package's `web.php` route file:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function(){
  $initData = [
    'appName' => config('app.name'),
    'user' => Auth::user(),
];
  return view('laravue-spa::app', compact('initData'));
})->middleware(['web']);
```

Comment: include in the documentation for them to not define their own route for '/', or to point to your controller for '/' .... and your package shouldn't be defining a closure based route, they won't be able to cache their routes if you do

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for the tip on the closure route.  The default Laravel install has a `/` route so I was hoping to override that but if I must include removing it in the install instructions then that's what I'll do.

Comment: it is their routes and their application, what is there by default is only there for example purposes anyway

Comment: @lagbox It's actually a package for creating a single page application so they never need to touch the routes file other than commenting the default one out but I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but for someone else:

You can ask the user to disable the auto package discovery in their `composer.json` and then manually register the package's Service Provider before the `RouteServiceProvider` in `config/app.php`